# Парсим XML при помощи javascript из под java

Tags: xml, парсер, java, javascript

Вот это каламбур :), итак стоит задача сделать выше указанное, для этого использую следующее:

- `javax.script.*` из `java` который позволяет выполнять код `javascritp`
- `new DOMParser()` из `javascritp` который позволяет парсить `XML`

До этого данный механизм использовался для парсинга текстовых файлов(то есть `new DOMParser()` не использовался) и все работало гладко.
Как только дошло дело до парсинга `XML` появилась ошибка:

```
sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.EcmaError: ReferenceError: "DOMParser" is not defined. (<Unknown source>#51) in <Unknown source> at line number 51
```

JAVA код:

```
public static HashMap<String, String> scripterSP(String dataIN, String Jscript){
    try{
        ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager();
        ScriptEngine rhinoEngine = manager.getEngineByName("javascript");
        Bindings bindings = rhinoEngine.getBindings(ScriptContext.ENGINE_SCOPE);

        bindings.put("text", dataIN);
        rhinoEngine.eval(Jscript.toString());

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        HashMap<String, String> hm = (HashMap<String, String>) bindings.get("map");

        return hm;
    } catch (ScriptException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        err = e.getMessage();
        return null;    
    }

}
```

javascript код:

```
map = {};
function getElementsList(doc) {
    nodeArr = new Array();
    parser = new DOMParser();
    xml = parser.parseFromString(doc,"text/xml");
...
...
...
парсер достаточно длинный и никому ненужный
его суть в наполнении словаря map
...
}
getElementsList(text);
```

ошибка показывает на эту строку

```
parser = new DOMParser();
```

Может кто то сталкивался с подобным ? Возможно есть какой то еще способ объявить `DOMParser` ?

**UPD**

> DOMParser is not part of JS but part
> of Mozilla browser which makes it
> available to script in the browser
> using XPConnect. An alternative would
> be to use built-in E4X.

[источник](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Newsgroup_summaries/mozilla-dev-tech-js-engine/JS-Engine_FAQ)

и

> E4X is implemented in Rhino
> (JavaScript engine written in Java).

[источник](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/E4X)

**UPD2**
E4X - не работает 
такая же ошибка

**UPD3**
Не совсем решение проблемы, но тем не менее работает:
модифицируем наш класс

```
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Map;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

import javax.script.Bindings;
import javax.script.ScriptContext;
import javax.script.ScriptEngine;
import javax.script.ScriptEngineManager;
import javax.script.ScriptException;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;

public static Map<String, String> scripterSP(String dataIN, String Jscript){
    Document document;
    DocumentBuilderFactory factory=DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    factory.setValidating(false);
    try{
        ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager();
        ScriptEngine rhinoEngine = manager.getEngineByName("javascript");
        Bindings bindings = rhinoEngine.getBindings(ScriptContext.ENGINE_SCOPE);
        document = builder.parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(dataIN.getBytes()));
        bindings.put("text", document);
        rhinoEngine.eval(Jscript.toString());

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        Map<String, String> m = (Map<String, String>) bindings.get("map");

        return m;
    } catch (ScriptException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        err = e.getMessage();
        return null;    
    }

}
```

теперь в javascript мы можем работать с `text` также как и в java

Как работать с этим чудом :

есть такой xml:

```
<TD>
<T CValue='78ECE5' Version='20050329_TEST_00000002' />
<T CValue='30B2C9' Version='20050329_TEST_00000001' />
</TD>
```

для него пишем такой javascript:

```
root = text.getDocumentElement();
t = text.getDocumentElement().getElementsByTagName('T');
map = {};
map[1]= root.getTagName();
map[2]= t.item(0).getAttributes().item(0);
map[3]= t.item(0).getAttributes().item(1);
```

и если потом распарсить полученный MAP в java на key value то получим :

```
1 = TD
2 = CValue="78ECE5"
3 = Version="20050329_TEST_00000002"
```

ЗЫ

Плохо то что будет требоваться знать как работать с DOM в java, то есть немного отходим от синтаксиса javascript, так что если будут какие либо предложения или идеи, не стесняйтесь отписываться.

Comment: Компилятор четко говорит, что функция DOMParser не определена, её не существует! Видимо в вашем модуле отсутствует эта функция.

Comment: Это происходит из-за того что javascript использует функции браузера и вроде как DOMParser стандартизирован для большинства браузеров, а я запускаю это при помощи модуля java(не в браузере , код парсера запущенный в браузере работает корректно), так вот собственно вопрос "есть какой то еще способ объявить DOMParser ?", можно перефразировать "есть еще какие нибудь механизмы разбора XML в javascript которые переведут текст в DOM object ?"

Comment: Меня сейчас отругают, но можно и вот так:

 var div = document.createElement("div")
 div.innerHTML = "<element>123</element>";
 div.querySelectorAll("*");

Comment: sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.EcmaError: ReferenceError: "document" is not defined.

Comment: Задача чисто гипотетическая, или начальство требует сделать только так и ни как больше?

Comment: Задача "рабочая", есть интерфейс на нем можно загрузить/написать скрипт и текст для разбора, для этого используется выше указанный механизм, если есть идеи как можно реализовать по другому, то я весь во внимании :D

ЗЫ
обязательные условия написано на java, для скриптов использовать javascript

ЗЫЫ 
я так понимаю у Вас было какое то предложения(возможно не совсем подходящее), но Вы его все равно озвучьте :)

Comment: @sonniy попробуй заменить document на window.document (в моем коде).

Comment: @lampa все та же беда `"any" is not defined.`